# Pedestrian proof of Gaussian chaos for order-two polynomial?

Tags: pr.probability, inequalities, stochastic-calculus, gaussian

Let $\ell \geqslant 1$. Let us consider $(g_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ identically distributed independent real gaussian variables and real number $(a_{n_1,\dots n_{\ell}})_{(n_1, \dots, n_{\ell}s)\in\mathbb{N}^{\ell}}$. We consider the random variable
$$G(\omega)=\sum_{n_1, \dots, n_{\ell}}a_{n_1, \dots, n_{\ell}} g_{n_1}(\omega) \cdots g_{n_{\ell}}(\omega)$$
where we write $\omega \in \Omega$ the probability space at hand.

It is known as Gaussian polynomial chaos (or Wiener chaos)
$$\|G(\omega)\|_{L^p_{\Omega}} \lesssim p^{\frac{\ell}{2}} \|G(\omega)\|_{L^2_{\Omega}}.$$

The standard proof of this results uses hypercontractivity of the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck semigroup.

My question is the following: in the case $\ell =2$ and $p=2k$ an even integer,

> Is it possible to prove "directly by hand" that
> $$\mathbb{E}[|G(\omega)|^{2k}] \leqslant C k^{2k}\mathbb{E}[|G(\omega)|^2]^k.$$
> If yes, is there a reference book/article to find it? Or is it possible to finish my attempted proof?

This does not seem impossible. At least, when one expands the left-hand side, we have
$$\mathbb{E}[|G(\omega)|^{2k}] = \sum_{\substack{n_1,\dots ,n_k\\ m_1, \dots, m_k}}a_{n_1,m_1} \dots a_{n_{2k},m_{2k}}\mathbb{E}[g_{n_1}g_{m_1}\cdots g_{n_{2k}}g_{m_{2k}}].$$

From there, one can use the fact that $\mathbb{E}[g^{2m+1}]=0$ for any $m$ to infer that in the above, the expectation is non-vanishing only if the indices ${n_i, m_i}$ appear an even number of time. So in particular, all $n_i, m_i$ are paired.

The right hand side reads
$$k^{2k}\mathbb{E}[|G(\omega)|^2]^k = k^{2k}\sum_{\substack{n_1,\dots ,n_k\\ m_1, \dots, m_k}}a_{n_1,m_1} \dots a_{n_{2k},m_{2k}}\prod_{i=1}^k\mathbb{E}[g_{n_i}g_{m_i}g_{n_{k+i}}g_{m_{k+i}}].$$

Also, remark that in the LHS, when all the $g_i$ are equal, then we have $\mathbb{E}[g^{4k}] \lesssim k^{2k}$, which is the correct magnitude which we look for.

However I am not able to prove that $\text{LHS} \leqslant \text{RHS}$. But I remain convinced that there should be somewhere to find such a proof but I did not locate it in the literature.

Comment: Try section 4.1 of http://eprints.biblio.unitn.it/1189/1/UTM711.pdf by Da Prato and Tubaro. There is also the book Gaussian Hilbert Spaces by Janson, Chapter V.

Comment: Why you call it "order-two polynomial" in the title? Janson's reference provided by Abdelmalek Abdesselam is pretty  good one. Janson also opens parentheses and connects the resulted expression with "Feynman diagrams". See also Exercise 9.37 and 9.38 in Ryan's book https://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~amnon/Classes/2016-PRG/Analysis-Of-Boolean-Functions.pdf and references therein.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam thank you very much, this answers my question!

Comment: @PaataIvanishvili I called it "order-two polynomial" because I was particularly interested in the order-two case (see the end of my post), because it is a nice toy model to study.